# side bar position in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have header nav bar and Side nav bar named vertical menu. I couldn't fix the position of my nav bar close to float left.  It is having some gaps, I tried adjusting the position still missing something. Please see image for reference [image]

In case if I include another menu now , if I click profile that also kind of not working out, because of the position of the side nav bar.

```
 <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>






<nav class="navbar top-color">
    <!--nav header Div-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="navbar-head" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" href="#"><h1>Bootstrap Case</h1></a>
      </div>


    </div>


  </nav>




<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse verticalmenu" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Main Menu</a>
      <br><br>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#/dashboard"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard vmenu"></span>  Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user vmenu"></span> Profile</a>
      </li>
         <li><a href="#/skilltest"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit vmenu"></span>Skill Test</a>
      </li>
         <li><a href="#/interviews"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags vmenu"></span>Interviews</a>
      </li>
         <li><a href="#/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off vmenu"></span>Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>a
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

CSS :

```
 <style>
.top-color {
      background-color: aquamarine;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .firstmenu {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }



@media (min-width: 768px) {


          .top-color{
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        height:5em;
        padding-top:10px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #3399ff;
        padding-bottom: 30px;

    } 
        .firstmenu .navbar-brand {
        padding-left:155px;
    }
         .firstmenu li{
        padding-left:50px;


    }


        .firstmenu .active{
            width:250px;


        }

        select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
        }


    .verticalmenu .navbar-toggle {
  display: none ;
}
.navbar.verticalmenu {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
    }
.verticalmenu .collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse {
  display: block;
  float: left;

}
    .verticalmenu .active {
            width:200px;

        }


     .verticalmenu .navbar-collapse {
        height: auto;
        border-top: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        max-height: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    .verticalmenu  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: block !important;
        width: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
      }
     .verticalmenu .navbar-collapse.in {
        overflow-x: visible;
      }
    .verticalmenu  .navbar {
        max-width: 100px;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
     .verticalmenu .navbar-nav,
      .verticalmenu .navbar-nav > li,
     .verticalmenu .navbar-left,
     .verticalmenu .navbar-right,
     .verticalmenu .navbar-header {
        float: none !important;
      }
     .verticalmenu .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        left: 0;
        right: auto;
      }
    .verticalmenu  .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
      }

     .vmenu{
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: do you mean that you want the sidebar nav to be on the far left with no gap ?

Comment: Yes , Without any gap.

Comment: try the code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

change the below selector

```
.navbar.verticalmenu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:none` from `.verticalmenu .navbar-header`.